# Leverage Singleton Spring Bean Constructor to instantiate unsafe Thead methods

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, schema

Lets say I have a Singleton Spring Bean Foo.
I want it to do some Schema validation using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html - which is not thread safe. If I put the unsafe methonds within the Constructor of my singleton bean, would this be a good approach? As I see it, the bean will only be created once, thus is CTR will only be called once. In essence, only 1 thread will ever call the unsafe code, i.e. the Thread that creates the bean...

Thanks,
Damien

Full code below:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
private javax.xml.validation.Validator validator;
private JAXBContext jc;

// Exception omitted
public FooImpl() {

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderType.class);

ClassLoader classLoader = OrderType.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream xsdStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("myXsd.xsd");

Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
// The unsafe thread code... 
// Perhaps I should synch this code...
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);

validator = schema.newValidator();
}

// Exception omitted
public void validateOrder(final Object in) {
validator.validate(new JAXBSource(jc, in));
}
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right: there's no problem if you put that thread-unsafe stuff into the constructor, as long as your schema validation code does not rely on other Spring-managed beans. (And given you don't call the constructory by your own means)...

Comment: It will work, however constructor is absolutely a no place for code like this.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I appreciate that this type of code would not belong in a CTR and would move it into its own config bean, which in turn can be injected. Stepping back, do u have any comments on the general approach - as it does not seem right to me. An alternative would be to move all the above code into an instance method and mark it (or at least the  appropriate line ) as synchronized.